# Loading procedure for Datawarehouse SSIS or Stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

We are working on Data warehousing project where we get data from different sources. We use SSIS packge to get data from source to warehouse server and load dimension and fact using Stored procedures. We may append more databases to existing warehouse that we are creating.

What would be easier process to manage SSIS packages and Stored procedures ?
Would it be faster to call sp from SSIS package or deploy SSIS package to server and call both using SQL Agent Job ?

What we do in order to maintain SSIS package and SP's which will execute daily, weekly, Monthly ?

Comment: What version of SSIS? As stated I don't understand your two questions. What do you mean by 'maintain'?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid 2012 SQL Server and 2010 SSDT. Maintain means what is best way to run monthly or daily packages and how to store them ?

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 you should use project based (not package based), deploy to the SSIS catalog (i.e. in the database). To schedule them put them in a SQL Agent job

Comment: Packages that you actually edit are stored as .dtsx files. You should deploy them to the SSIS Catalog when running them.

Comment: Justin. I'm afraid nothing you've asked so far has made any sense. Do you have a specific problem you are trying to solve? Have you opened up SSDT, built a package and deployed it?

Answer (score 2):

As a general principle we use SSIS packages to manage execution logging, but to only be a 'wrapper' to call stored procedures - even in SQL 2012 & 2014.

Advantages are

- SSIS is XML and doing code comparison/merging is impossible, so keep the complexity out of SSIS
- SSIS is generally not optimal at set based operations. Native T-SQL is superior as a general rule
- SPs can be code controlled very easily and doing diff/merge can be done quickly
- Automated creation of SPs is very simple using meta data, as compared to automated generation of the same types of logic within SSIS (we are very much into meta-data generated systems)

As far as execution, we call the 'Master SSIS' package, which has a set of meta data that determines what child packages can be called when and what degree of parallelism you want. The meta data also contains information as to the schedule of the 'Master SSIS' package and what type of load it is daily, weekly, monthly, adhoc, etc.

Comment: I have built exactly the same master package/paralellism/metadata/parameter thing but in SQL 2008. It's interesting to note that the same requirement is still not met in SQL2012

Comment: Any example of SSIS package or do you know if i can find any package on web to reference it ? Appreciate your help..

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid ... or 2014! I don't think there is improvement in 2016 either in this area!

Comment: @Justin The real work is involved in constructing the meta-data and the ability to instanciate each SSIS task with appropriate locking to get logging working. The SSIS is a fairly minimal structure that just has a call to a Stored Procedure the name of which is passed as a parameter.